# Update /etc/apt/sources.list before or after the actual debian upgrade process

Tags: debian, upgrade

I want to run an upgrade `debian10` --> `debian11`.

I am going through the official [instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html).

Should the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` be changed to reflect `bullseye` **BEFORE** running the actual upgrade command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions tell you to [update `/etc/apt/sources.list` in section 4.3](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrade-process), and *then* [perform the upgrade in section 4.4](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgradingpackages). In short, the process is

1. Upgrade your system so it has the latest Debian 10 packages (`buster`)
2. Edit `sources.list` to reference Debian 11 (`bullseye`)
3. Upgrade your system to Debian 11 (in two steps, first [a minimal  upgrade](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade) and then [the full upgrade](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrading-full))